# Can I make ValidationMessageFor display hint on valid data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following scenario. A form has a few inputs and under some of them there are hints like "you don't have to fill this field" etc. Now I want the regular validation messages to replace those hints if a validation error appears. When the field is valid again the hint doesn't have to show up again (I wouldn't mind if it showed up though).

Is it possible to achieve that using the standard ValidationMessageFor helper?

---

I guess I could patch something up using JS, since I'm already monitoring  the element which contains validation message for class changes (using http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/), so I can change the color of a whole control group on validation error.

In this case I would just need to show\hide the hint depending on whether the validation error is visible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution I used looks like this. I encapsulated each input paired with validation message inside a 'control-group' div. Then I used attrchange to monitor validation span changes.

In View:

```
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Something)
    <p class="help-block">This is a hint.</p>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Something)
</div>
```

In css:

```
.control-group.error .help-block
{
     display:none;
}
```

In JS:

```
function UpdateControlGroupErrorState(valmsg) {
    valmsg = $(valmsg);
    var controlGroup = valmsg.closest('.control-group');
    if (controlGroup.find('.field-validation-error').length > 0) {
        if (!controlGroup.hasClass("error")) {
            controlGroup.addClass("error");
        }
    }
    else {
        if (controlGroup.hasClass("error")) {
            controlGroup.removeClass("error");
        }
    }
}

function SetupGroupValidate(validators) {
    validators.each(function () {
        UpdateControlGroupErrorState(this);
        $(this).attrchange({
            trackValues: true,
            callback: function (e) {
                if (e.attributeName == "class") {
                    UpdateControlGroupErrorState(this);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}


$(function () {
    var validators = $('.control-group span[data-valmsg-for]');
    SetupGroupValidate(validators);
});
```